# MongoDB: Converting String to Date within Projection

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp, projection

I got the following MongoDQ query:

```
db.entries.aggregate([
  {"$sort" : {"display_time" : -1}}, 
  {"$project": { 
            "ts":  { "$max": "$display_time" } ,
            "value": { "$avg": "$price" }
    }
}
]);
```

, where display_time is a String of the format "2018-07-20T15:45:00+02:00".
I am trying to convert it to a timestamp, but couldn't get it done.

Is there anyone that could help, please?

Thank you! :)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html